# NSUserDefaults to Detect First Time Launch and UISwitch Glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

This is the code I have:

***FirstViewController***

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // app already launched
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // This is the first launch ever

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        InitialViewController *viewController = (InitialViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

And Here is my settings view controller:

Settings View Controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
        [showinstructionsonstartup setOn:YES animated:YES];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else {
        [showinstructionsonstartup setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    if (showinstructionsonstartup.on) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

For some reason, this code is returning a weird output: I am trying to see 2 things: 1. If my user is a first time user and 2. If my user has set the switch to see the instructions that would run for a first time user. For some weird reason, sometimes when I set the switch off (no instructions), it stays set no until I reopen the app, and it takes me straight into the directions. Does anyone know why it does this?

Comment: Why do you call `synchronize` on `NSUserDefaults` so many times? You don't need to call it all. But if must, just do it once.

Answer (score 0):

I thing your overall design is poor. You should load user settings in your application delegate (`applicationDidLaunch:`) and use the delegate or a settings object when your view controllers want to know the value of a setting, or change setting. You can easily get your app delegate using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`. For one thing, `viewDidAppear` can be called more than once for a given `UIView`

Comment: PS: Yes, this does not answer your question directly, but sometimes problems go away when your design is improved.

Comment: do you have a direct answer?